# Clickonce deployment with SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I manage to finish my project and publish it for deployment on other machines. My C# WPF application have SQL Server CE as its backend database. I wanted the database to be able to work in other machine that have no SQL Server CE installed. I publish it using clickonce, the publish was successful. However when I run it on other machines, and tries to open the database there is an error prompt that said 'database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database `[Data Source=D:db.sdf]`. I followed the tutorials on clickonce by mdsn, Microsoft and by other people, the result is always the same. The local database cannot be detected.

Answer (score 1):

`D:db.sdf` is not created by ClickOnce, you must have changed something. ClickOnce by default installs data that is included in a project to a directory in the app folder, and sets the `DataDirectory` app domain value to the path to this directory. In your application you should use something like

```
SqlConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf;...")
```

Note that `DataDirectory` may not be writable by users. If you want users to save data you should copy `|DataDirectory|db.sdf` to some place writable like

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```